# Arrays and For Loop (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This is probably a simple question, but how do I display "not in array" 1 time if the value I declared before isn't in the array? I got it to display "in array" by using an enhanced for loop to loop through the array. I noticed that if I added an else after the if, it would display "not in array" 4 times.

I'm still new to programming and have read the chapter, but I get so confused when it comes to arrays and for loops. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // Creating an array
    int number = 5;                 // My test number

    // Enhanced for loop
    for (int val: test) {
        if (number == val) {
            System.out.println(number + " in array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `boolean` variable that you set to  `true` if the number was found (and as soon as the number is found, `break;` from the loop). Depending on its final value, display what you want after the `for` loop .

Comment: To add to Berger statement, create a `boolean` to `false` to start with! Then set it to `true` if the value is found.

Comment: For the sake of functional style... if (Arrays.stream(test).anyMatch(((Integer)number)::equals))

Comment: @Alexander Anikin I tried copying that and it doesn't work for me. What am I forgetting to do? Also, can you explain to me what this line means?

Comment: @Alexander Anikin I had to import java.util.Arrays, but can you still explain the line

Comment: @ShinoOG It's example of java Streams api. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the flags,

```
boolean found = false; 
for (int val: test) {
    if (number == val) {
        //System.out.println(number + " in array");
       //set the flag if found 
       found=true;
       //stop once you found what you looking for
       break;
    }
}
//check if the flag is set
if(!found)
    System.out.println(number + " is not in array")
```

Comment: So it starts off as false correct? and if the number == val then the variable gets changed to true? Does !found mean if it is not true, the print not in array?  @NishanthSpShetty

Comment: @ShinoOG `!found` means `not found` it's the same as `found == false`

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty but the variable found is now set to true only because number == val, correct?

Comment: Yes @ShinoOG, that's what should be said in the explanation of the code ;)

Comment: @AxeIH sorry, I just wanted to double check

Comment: Would it be fair to conclude that a boolean flag is the best way to determine if x is in an array?

Comment: @ShinoOG yes, its one of the simple and elegant way of checking something resulting in boolean outcome. but i wouldnt say best way of determining if x is in array.

Comment: Thank you EVERYONE for the feedback. I'm sure this was a very basic problem, but I just have a hard time understand arrays and for loops. Does anyone have any practice problems that involve arrays and for loops?

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental issue is that you can't know if an item is not in any position in an unsorted array until you have looped through all the items. If you check each item individually, you can't know if the next item might match.

Use a boolean variable to keep track of whether you've seen the item, and only print the result after the loop, once you've gone through all of them. Also check out `break`, you can use it to exit the loop if you don't need it to go all the way through.

After you've figured that out, a good next exercise is to extract the loop into a separate method and use `return` instead of `break`. Then you won't even need the boolean variable anymore.

Comment: "you can't know if an item is not in any position in the array until you have looped through all the items" Not true for a sorted array, which this one happens to be.

Comment: @Michael that's not a certitude, since this is not specified in the question this is just a coincidence that this array is sorted.

Comment: If I did it the way @NishanthSpShetty did it, do I still need to break the loop?

Comment: @AxelH I know it's not certain, but that doesn't mean it **is** a coincidence. It means it **might** be a coincidence. It's definitely worth noting that sorted arrays present the opportunity for more efficient search algorithms. This answer to me implies that arrays always require an exhaustive search which is not correct.

Comment: @ShinoOG yes, breaking would be a best option, lets say you have list of 1000 int's and you found the value in the beginning, then looping over all the values is a waste.

Comment: True @Michael, I did the same thing, I forgot the "might" be.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty okay, that makes sense